# Static shock on a device on a different circuit causes PC keyboard backlight to blink

Tags: grounding

When I touch an electric space heater, sometimes there'll be a static discharge. No big deal but what's odd is that every time this happens, the backlights on a USB keyboard plugged into a PC blink off momentarily (they're supposed to be always on). But the PC is plugged into a circuit with a different circuit breaker.

Is that something to be expected, or could it be an indicator that something is off with our grounding? I don't care about stopping the keyboard blinking, it could decide to stop working tomorrow and I'll gladly drop kick it into the garbage, but grounding issues I definitely care about.

Comment: Could just be RFI. A spark puts out radio noise.

Comment: Interesting thought, this is a wired keyboard.. but maybe it's not ground related at all. Must be a pretty junk bit of electronics in there.

Comment: IMO an indicator of a not greatly built keyboard picking up RF interference. Quite possibly the LEDs are the *only* thing affected and it doesn't really matter, just an oddity. If you have problems with wi-fi or your boomer grandparents can't listen to the AM radio, then replace the keyboard or turn the LEDs off...